# Fake 3D, animation. What is faster: img or css sprites?

Tags: html, css, animation, interactive

In order to create interactive fake 3D animation as on this site:
http://finnrudolph.de/JavaScriptObject/

Or those interactive animations on Apples iPad features page (halfway down):
http://www.apple.com/ipad/features/

What is faster, CSS Sprites or imgs?

(At least semantically, using img makes more sense I think.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your are using **vector shapes** that `sprite` is better but if your are using **images** like this `car pic's`, `mountain pic's` etc. Then `sperate images` (IMG Tag) are better.

SO, if you are using **images** then `<img>` is perform better then `sprite`.